# two dynamic bodies intersecting or overlaping in cocos2d-x v3.2

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

Using cocos2d-x v3.2, I have tow dynamic bodies bodyA and bodyB. And bodyB has gravity disabled and has a linear velocity across x-axis. bodyA has an impulse across y-axis. The problem is bodyA is passing through bodyB. The expected result is bodyA collides with bodyB, bodyA bounced away while bodyB is not impacted by the collision. Here is the sample code where bodyA passes through bodyB.

```
PhysicsBody *bodyA = PhysicsBody::createCircle(spriteA->getContentSize().width/2);
bodyA->setDynamic(true);
bodyA->setMass(0.5f);
bodyA->setCategoryBitmask(1);
bodyA->setContactTestBitmask(true);

PhysicsBody *bodyB = PhysicsBody::createCircle(spriteB->getContentSize().width/2);
bodyB->setDynamic(true);
bodyB->setGravityEnable(false);
bodyB->setVelocity(Vect(100,0));
bodyB->setCollisionBitmask(2);
bodyB->setContactTestBitmask(true);
bodyB->setMass(5.0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setContactTestBitmask` doesn't take a bool, it should take an int which is a bitmask that should contain all the category bits that the body should collide with.

Right now your two bodies have bits 0001 and 0010 set. Your contact bitmask however has bit 0001 set for both bodies. Also you use category bitmask in bodyA and collision bitmask in bodyB.

This way ought to work:

```
PhysicsBody *bodyA = PhysicsBody::createCircle(spriteA->getContentSize().width/2);
bodyA->setCategoryBitmask(1);
bodyA->setContactTestBitmask(2);

PhysicsBody *bodyB = PhysicsBody::createCircle(spriteB->getContentSize().width/2);
bodyB->setCategoryBitmask(2);
bodyB->setContactTestBitmask(1);
```

Or even better: don't modify the default bitmasks until you absolutely need to.

Comment: Thanks. I set that to bool after watching [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ow91oT5uIp0&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf4dOgNrnQCw1DyIFGUhnVtZ&index=7). I edited my code as you suggested but still the same result.

Comment: try without setting the bitmasks

Comment: Without bitmasks set, the bodyB gets impacted by collision with bodyA and moves away. And my requirement is bodyB should not move away (along y-axis) after collision with bodyA which is moving along y-axis. bodyB should only be moving in linear velocity.